# UIImagePickerController not working in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I written this code for presentViewController[UIImagePickerController]. If I click the Library button or camera button, it doesn't work.

How can I fix this code?

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    if (buttonIndex== 0) {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            }
            else{
                [CommonMethods showAlert:@"Error" MSG:@"Device has no camera"];
            }
    }
    else if (buttonIndex== 1){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1.

Comment: Please provide more info. Exactly what is not working? the whole method doesn't get called at all? or it gets called, but it doesn't present the camera/library view controller? have you tried setting breakpoints to see what actually happens? Are you testing it in iOS Simulator or on an actual device? (not sure about PhotoLibrary, but SourceTypeCamera is not available on iOS simulator), Do you alloc-init the UIImagePickerController object someplace?

Comment: I allocated in UIImagePickerController in Viewdidload and given delegate self to that UIImagePickerController object.I'm showing the one actionsheet in this I put the two button "Camera" and "Library".